# Event To get Refund Order in Magento2

Tags: magento2

i want to perform some action if click on credit memo of any order from admin what code i need to write in observer and what event i need to use

Answer (score 0):

You can use **sales_order_save_after** event to perform some actions.

create **events.xml** in your namespace->module->etc->adminhtml->events.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_after">
        <observer name="order_sync_observer" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\SyncOrder" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create class in Namepsace->Module->Observer->SyncOrder.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager;

class SyncOrder implements ObserverInterface
{

//   protected $logger;
  public $order;
  public $product;
  protected $eavConfig;
  protected $customerRepository;
  
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order, 
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $product, 
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
  )
  {

    $this->order = $order;
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;


  }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {


    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
   
  
    }

}
```